# Not geting data from return inside firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting data from the firebase but able to it on emulator I tried using consloe which workfine

```
const Getdata = async () => {
    await firebase.database().ref(`/orders/${user1.uid}`)
    .on("child_added", (snapshot, key) => {
        if(snapshot.key) {
            console.log('key',snapshot.key);
            let grabbedData = snapshot.val().orders;
            grabbedData.map((order, i) => {
                console.log('order',order.id);
                console.log('order',order.avatar);
                console.log('order',order.name);
                console.log('order',order.price);
                console.log('----------------');
            });
        }
        
    });
}
Getdata();
```

After modifing the above code as below code nothing is showing to the screen

```
const Getdata = () => {
        let data = firebase.database().ref(`/orders/${user1.uid}`)
            .on("child_added", (snapshot, key) => {
             // something is wrong with this below statememnt I think
                return (
                    <Card>
                        <Text>{snapshot.key}</Text>
                        {
                            snapshot.val().orders.map((order, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity  key={i} onPress={() => {
                                    }}>
                                        <Card>
                                            <View style={styles.user}>
                                            <Image
                                                style={styles.image}
                                                resizeMode="cover"
                                                source={{ uri: order.avatar }}
                                            />
                                            <View style={{flexDirection:'column', flex: 1}}>
                                                <Text style={styles.name} h4>{order.name}</Text>
                                                <Card.Divider style={{ marginTop: 25}}/>
                                                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex: 1,justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                                <Text style={styles.price}>{order.price}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            </View>
                                            </View>
                                        </Card>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </Card>

                )
                    
                
        })
        return data;
    }

and then <Getdata/>
```

Something I am doing wrong with first return statememnt but dont know what.
Edit I am adding a pic how data is organised [image]

Comment: `on()` neither returns a promise, not does it return data.  So, the way you're using it in both cases is incorrect.  Did you mean to use `once()` instead, which does return a promise with database data?

Comment: But using once get data only once and want it to be realtime

Comment: You're going to have to choose if you want the function to return data or listen is real time.  You can't do both at once with the same API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]); // initially empty
const [key, setKey] = useState(undefined); // undefined empty

const Getdata = async () => {
    await firebase.database().ref(`/orders/${user1.uid}`)
    .on("child_added", (snapshot, key) => {
        if(snapshot.key) {
            console.log('key',snapshot.key);
            let grabbedData = snapshot.val().orders;
            setKey(snapshot.key); // set key here
            setOrders(grabbedData); // set orders here to state, it will rerender
        }
        
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    Getdata();
});


return (
                    <Card>
                        {key && <Text>{snapshot.key}</Text>}
                        {
                            orders.map((order, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity  key={i} onPress={() => {
                                    }}>
                                        .........
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </Card>

)
```

Comment: Thnx this works but it print last object contents and remaining are excluded

Comment: And I have added pic to better understand